# Overriding presence true in User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-presence

I have the following in my models/user.rb:

```
validates :company, presence: true
validates :title, presence: true
```

I have a secondary view where I want to create a user but not require this user to enter a company and a title. How would I do that without modifying the main user.rb?

This is for Rails 3.2

Comment: In that case you can use the client side validations like jQuery validation plugin on just one view rather than having it declared in model itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by declaring custom validations the way @BroiSatse has answered or when saving the user you can pass `validate: false` as argument, do this way

```
@user.save(:validate => false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do sth like:

```
class User < AR::Base

  validates :company, :title, presence: true, if: :validate_company_and_title?

  def validate_company_and_title?
    @validate_company_and_title.nil? || @validate_company_and_title
  end

  def skip_company_and_title_validation!
    @validate_company_and_title = false  
  end
end
```

Then in your controller create action for given view you can do:

```
@user.skip_company_and_title_validation!
```